# Is there a way to detect whether the FCP file export completed or not, via CLI

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, final-cut-pro, fcpx

I want to post-process the video file exported from FCP, using FFmpeg.

Currently, I firstly do "Share" on FCP and wait for completion, then trigger the FFmpeg.

However, I'd like to make these bothering steps into one, using shell-script like as follows:

```
$ __COMMAND_THAT_WAIT_FOR_EXPORT_COMPLETION__ fcp-output.mov
$ ffmpeg -i fcp-output.mov __OPTIONS__  processed-file.mp4
```

Is there an equivalent to `__COMMAND_THAT_WAIT_FOR_EXPORT_COMPLETION__` above?

Answer (score 0):

The tool [Command Post](https://commandpost.io/) could be what you looking for.

Comment: Thx. However, glancing at [the features](https://help.commandpost.io/getting-started/features) of CommandPost, I could not find a function I was looking for.